# Images not printing with textattachfile

Tags: graphics, attachfile

When include graphics is put inside textattachfile from the attachfile2 package the image does not appear in the print preview or actual printing when using acrobat reader. Is it possible to get it to print without needing to resort to an online version and a version for printing?

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{attachfile2,graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \textattachfile{image.png}{\includegraphics{image.png}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-printing seems to be a bug in AR because the print flag is set.

As workaround the image can be put outside of `\textattachfile`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{attachfile2,graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \leavevmode
  \rlap{\includegraphics{image.png}}%
  \textattachfile{image.png}{\phantom{\includegraphics{image.png}}}
\end{document}
```